# How can I group multiples input in one output

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008, etl, ssis

I have an Excel like this

```
region    state    city
-------------------------
south     state1    city1
north     state2    city2
```

and I want to fill a data base table like this

```
  id      name       type
 ------------------------
   1      state1     state
   2      south      region
   3      city1      city
```

But I don't have any idea about how to group these columns and headers to fill the data base table. Any ideas? I'm pretty lost with this app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in SSIS using `Unpivot Transformation` available in `Data Flow Task`. Following example illustrates how this can be done. The example uses `SSIS 2008 R2` and `SQL 2008 R2` database.

**Step-by-step process:**

1. Create an Excel file with sample data as shown in screenshot #**1**. I have named the file as **Source.xlsx**.
2. Create a table in the SQL Server database named `dbo.Destination` using the script given under **SQL Scripts** section. This table will be populated with Excel data. I have introduced a new field named **GroupId** so the data can be grouped together.
3. On the SSIS package, create an Excel connection named Excel and an OLE DB connection named SQLServer as shown in screenshot #**2**. `Excel connection manager` should be configured as shown as in screenshot #**3**. OLE DB connection will be configured to connect to the database of your choice.
4. On the package's `Control Flow` tab, place a `Data Flow Task` as shown in screenshot #**4**.
5. Configure the Data Flow tab as shown in screenshot #**5** with an `Excel source`, `Script component`, `Unpivot transformation` and an `OLE DB destination`.
6. Configure the `Excel Source` as shown in screenshots #**6** and #**7**. This will read the data from Excel file.
7. Configure the `Script Component` as **Transformation** and add an `Output` column as shown in screenshot #**8**. On the `Script` section, click `Edit Script` and replace the code with the code given under **Script Component Code** section.
8. Configure the Unpivot transformation as shown in screenshot #**9**. We don't want to transform the **GroupId**, so don't configure that but make it to `Pass Through`.
9. Configure the `OLE DB destination` as shown in screenshots #**10** and #**11**.
10. Screenshot #**12** shows data in the table `dbo.Destination` **before** the package execution.
11. Screenshot #**13** shows the package execution.
12. Screenshot #**14** shows data in the table `dbo.Destination` **after** the package execution.

Hope that helps.

**SQL Scripts:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Destination](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Type] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [GroupId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Destination] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**Script Component Code:**

**C#** code that can be used only in **`SSIS 2008 or above`**.

```
/* Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Script Component
*  Write scripts using Microsoft Visual C# 2008.
*  ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.*/

using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    int groupId = 1;
    public override void PreExecute()
    {
        base.PreExecute();
    }

    public override void PostExecute()
    {
        base.PostExecute();
    }

    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        Row.GroupId = groupId;
        groupId += 1;
    }
}
```

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: 1]

**Screenshot #2:**

[image: 2]

**Screenshot #3:**

[image: 3]

**Screenshot #4:**

[image: 4]

**Screenshot #5:**

[image: 5]

**Screenshot #6:**

[image: 6]

**Screenshot #7:**

[image: 7]

**Screenshot #8:**

[image: 8]

**Screenshot #9:**

[image: 9]

**Screenshot #10:**

[image: 10]

**Screenshot #11:**

[image: 11]

**Screenshot #12:**

[image: 12]

**Screenshot #13:**

[image: 13]

**Screenshot #14:**

[image: 14]

Comment: thanks for your help. Is there any chances that you have a tutorial or something like that. And again thanks for asking